# BinarySearch on Object Array List in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, binary-search, compareto

I am trying to perform binary search on an object array list. The user must type in admin number to perform search. Here is my code :

**File Controller class to read file from .text file**

```
public class FileController extends StudentApp{
private String fileName;

public FileController() {
    String fileName = "student.txt";
}

public FileController(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public ArrayList<String> readLine() {
    ArrayList<String> studentList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            studentList.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        fr.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " was not found");
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
    return studentList;
}
```

**Student Class with all the setter & getter and compareTo method**

```
public Student(String adminNo, String name, GregorianCalendar birthDate) {
    this.adminNo = adminNo;
    this.name = name;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

public Student(String record) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(record);
    sc.useDelimiter(";");
    adminNo = sc.next();
    name = sc.next();
    birthDate = MyCalendar.convertDate(sc.next());
    test1 = sc.nextInt();
    test2 = sc.nextInt();
    test3 = sc.nextInt();
}
public String toString(){
    return (adminNo + " " + name + " " + MyCalendar.formatDate(this.birthDate));
}

public static ArrayList<Student> readStudent(String file) {
    FileController fc = new FileController(file);
    ArrayList<Student> recs = new ArrayList<Student>();
    ArrayList<String> recsReturn = new ArrayList<String>();

    recsReturn = fc.readLine();

    for (int index = 0; index < recsReturn.size(); index++) {
        String input = recsReturn.get(index);
        recs.add(new Student(input));
    }

    return recs;
}


public int compareTo(Student s) {
    return Compare(this, s);
}

public int Compare(Student s1, Student s2){
    if(s1.getAdminNo().equals(s2.getAdminNo())) {
      return 0;
    }else{
      return 1;
    }
}
```

**Executable main method lies here, in StudentSearch Class**

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <Student> studentList = new ArrayList <Student> ();
    studentList = Student.readStudent("student.txt");
    Collections.sort(studentList);

    System.out.println("Enter student admin number: ");
    String searchAdminNo = sc.next();

    int pos = Collections.binarySearch(studentList, new   Student(searchAdminNo));
    System.out.println(pos);
}
```

I want to perform search by using the user input admin number. However, here's the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at StudentGradeApps.Student.<init>(Student.java:22)
at StudentGradeApps.StudentSearch.main(StudentSearch.java:14)
```

I think the problem lies at the compareTo method and my binary search. Because when I removed them, my program can get the array list fine. The error only occurs when I try to perform search on my object list. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is with String you are trying to parse to get Student record. Print the string before trying to split, you will get the fault.

Comment: What does that means? Because I try to search by admin number only. Isn't it supposed to split then can find the admin number from the whole record?

Comment: Did you write this code or not? You are passing a file here : Student.readStudent("student.txt"); and then it is internally splitting it in Student constructor.

Comment: @loki So what should I do to fix it? Can you give me some code examples like how to solve it? I really don't get what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message say, the exception is occurring within the `Student` constructor -

```
public Student(String record) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(record);
    sc.useDelimiter(";");
    adminNo = sc.next();
    name = sc.next();
    birthDate = MyCalendar.convertDate(sc.next());
    test1 = sc.nextInt();
    test2 = sc.nextInt();
    test3 = sc.nextInt();
}
```

You are invoking the constructor here -

```
int pos = Collections.binarySearch(studentList, new   Student(searchAdminNo));
```

`searchAdminNo` probably doesn't have that many tokens (delimited by `;`) as you are reading in the constructor.

Comment: In other words, for the constructor to work properly, `searchAdminNo` should have a value that looks something like - `"some_string;some_string;some_string;some_integer;some_integer_some_integer"`.

Comment: my searchAdminNo is just an admin number entered by user. Then it will go to the text file and find the record like 033333C;Peter Loh;1/09/1983;55;70;30; Only the first element is admin number

Comment: You can use the other version of the method [Collections#binarySearch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and provide a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your `Student` class. You will have to use the other constructor in the `Student`, which doesn't use the `Scanner`. Also note that the binary-search works only if the collection is sorted.

Comment: So that means my old code can't be used any more because there's no solution to fix from there and I need to re-code?

Comment: It looks like it should be, but just to make sure - is `Student` [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)? For objects to be sorted and searched, they must be `Comparable`. Need to see how you have implemented the `compareTo()` method. And, also you can definitely use your code but since it's not working it should be fixed, you know it.

Comment: Ya it is comparable by admin number. I did in the Student class last two methods.

Comment: Then you can replace `new Student(searchAdminNo)` with `new Student(searchAdminNo, null, null)`, in `int pos = Collections.binarySearch(studentList, new   Student(searchAdminNo));`.

Comment: The error message after I modified: The method binarySearch(List<? extends T>, T, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (String, null, null)

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, but don't change anything in your original code, Just follow what I said in my last comment and see what you get.

Comment: Oh it's fixed. Thanks a lot. But what's caused the problem? Is it my string searchAdminNo automatically used the string record that constructor?

Comment: Yes you are right, first the constructor - `public Student(String record)` was being invoked, now the other constructor - `public Student(String adminNo, String name, GregorianCalendar birthDate)`.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Really really thanks for spending your time to help me debug